# Correct JQuery ready() Statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

I've seen all three lines of below:

```
$().ready();
$(document).ready();
$(document.body).ready();
```

They all work, but which one is really the correct (or better) one to use? Taking in account the usage of the ready() event.

Comment: Which ones did you find in the docs for [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)? Use documented code.

Comment: Duplicated question, they are all equivalent.

Comment: I always use the $(document).ready(); variation. Just a personal preference though :-)

Comment: You could just also place your script tags at the bottom of your body tag. (In case you were planning on wrapping all your JS in .ready().)

Answer (score 2):

None of these, I use `$(function() {})` as it clutters the least, is shortest and very idiomatic.